# How can I push input value inside an array and update it in Nuxt 2?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, nuxt.js

I want to push the input value inside an array and update it from there. I also want to delete that value inside the array if the `textarea` is empty. But I couldn't do that because I was stuck in the first step. I'm sharing the codes with you.

```html
<div class="coffee-textarea">
  <InputTextarea
    ref="questionTextarea"
    class="mt-4"
    placeholder="Sorularınız?"
    :required="true"
    @input="addQuestion"
  />
</div>
```

This is the textarea component. Inside I'm emitting the value entered by saying:

```
@input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"
```

So I'm emitting value and receiving it without a problem. Next, I'm taking it to the `addQuestion` method.

```js
methods: {
  addQuestion(value) {
    const question = value
    this.selectedQuestions.push(question)
  },
  // ...
}
```

There is a `selectedQuestions` array which is empty inside the data object:

```js
data() {
  return {
    selectedQuestions: [],
    // ...
  }
}
```

Also I have the `selectCheckbox` method which is pushing the checkbox values inside the same array:

```js
methods: {
  selectCheckbox(text) {
    const index = this.selectedQuestions.indexOf(text)
    if (index !== -1) {
      this.selectedQuestions.splice(index, 1)
    } else {
      this.selectedQuestions.push(text)
    }
  },
  // ...
}
```

The result is not what I want obviously. `addQuestion` is adding a new array of items inside `selectedQuestions` for every character input.

In Vue.js devtools, the result looks like this when I'm typing "efe" in my textarea:
[Vue.js devtools result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEmgS.png)

In this `addQuestion` method, I want to push a new value into the `selectedQuestions` array. And I want to update that value based on the value input.  I also don't want to reset the `selectedQuestions` array in any way because I'm also pushing different values into the `selectedQuestions` array from `selectCheckbox` method. How can I solve this?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: `addQuestion` should be a lot more like what you already have with `selectCheckbox`.  Find the index of the existing text area value in the array.  If the index does not exist, push the text area value to the array.  If the index does exist, replace the value instead.  This will not work if text area values and checkbox values match.  If that's a concern, maybe switch to pushing objects instead of strings, where each object has a property identifying which input its text value comes from.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@change` instead of `@input`.

Difference between `@input` and `@change`:

- `@input` trigger when input value changes
- `@changed` trigger when element loses focus within value changes

MDN Web Docs: [`oninput`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event), [`onchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event)